# How to subtract VAT and calculate stamp duty?

Tags: education

This seems like a really silly thing to be confused by!

Recently we have purchased a house (yay!).

Stamp duty was calculated as 1% of (price-VAT). Where price is 450,000 and VAT is 13.5%.

My step by step way to calculate this was

```
VAT cost = (450,000/100)*13.5 = 60,750
Cost - VAT cost= 450,000 - 60,750 = 389,250
Stamp at 1% of that is 3,892.50
```

However, what was actually requested was calculated as follows. I don't understand this method:

```
450,000 / 113.5 = 3,964.75
```

This is matched by, for example independent websites like https://switcher.ie/mortgages/guides/stamp-duty/
[image]

How can there be two seemingly valid answers to the same question? What am I missing about the calculation?

(Stamp duty is already paid at this point so there are no legal ramifications in this!)

Comment: Tagged as education because I didn't find any other tag for something this basic :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which one is right, depends on whether the $450,000$ already include VAT.

#### Does not include VAT

If it does not then the first equation is right. Because then VAT$=13.5\%\cdot 450,000$ as you calculated.

#### Does include VAT

But if VAT is already included, then you have to do something else to calculate it. Because then

$$
   \text{VAT} = 13.5\% \cdot x
$$
and
$$
   450,000 = \text{total} = x+\text{VAT} = (100 + 13.5)\% \cdot x = 1.135x
$$
So now the price without VAT is $x = 450,000/1.135$ and 1% of that means dividing by 100 again, so you end up with
$$
   450,000/(1.135*100)=450,000/(113.5)
$$
as is the formula you found.

Putting together our formula for $x$ and our formula in this case impies
$$
   \text{VAT} = 13.5\% \cdot (450,000/1.135) = (13.5/113.5)\cdot 450,000
$$
and since $13.5/113.5 \neq 13.5/100 = 13.5\%$, this is in general not equal to the first case.